# Why this SQL query is returning null?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql_amorgia = "select * from fb_event where eventid='20'";
$res_amorgia = mysql_query($sql_amorgia);
$no_of_e = mysql_num_rows($res_amorgia);
```

When I print out $no_of_e it prints nothing. It should print 0 in case of null record. Isnt it?

please check!

Comment: [presumably it's `mysql_query` rather than `my_sql_query`?] Edit: oh, ok you've fixed it :)

Comment: What does that query return if you run it directly in mysql on the command line, for example?

Comment: Actually it is a web serice for iphone. I dump the output to a file in order to test. So nothing is written to the file. Neither any comparison is working like>: if($no_of_e ==0) or if ($no_of_e >=0) etc

Comment: try to print the values of `$sql_amorgia` and execute it in phpmyadmin

Comment: Shit, I m not so lazy developer. printed out query is working in SQL server when copy and pasted

Comment: [probably worth adding the tag 'php' to this question (assuming it is PHP and I'm not being silly :)]

Comment: ah, you solved it? cool. what turned out to be the problem?

Comment: If you've solved your problem post the solution as an answer. Please don't add "[Solved]" to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was using `mysql_num_rows()` instead of `mssql_num_rows()`. Because the database I was using was MS SQL Server 2005.

Thanks for your comments